# Late initialising error in flutter while working with firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I'm working on this app to help people find the fitting wine for their meal. Now I wanted the user to be able to select the specific meal he or she is currently enjoying to have a better prediction what wine fits best. Now I tried implementing that but I'm getting this late error field must be initialised... I think I know where its coming from but I dont know how to solve it this is the code of the screen:

```
class _AskSomellierStep4ScreenState extends State<AskSomellierStep4Screen> {
  late QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> _selectedSnapshot;
  List<String> dataLabel = [
    'Home',
    'Search',
    'Account',
  ];
  late Future resultsLoaded;

  getResults() async {
    var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(widget.wineOrMeal)
        .where('type', isEqualTo: widget.selectedCuisine)
        .get();
    setState(() {
      allResults = data.docs;
    });
    filterResultsList();
    return data.docs;
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
...
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 35,
                top: 5,
              ),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 370,
                width: 320,
                child: Center(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemCount: filteredResults.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => widget.mealVSWine
                        ? PrefInformationCardWine(
                            snapShotDocument: filteredResults[index],
                            cardColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            isSelected:
                                filteredResults[index] == _selectedSnapshot,
                            onSelected: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _selectedSnapshot = filteredResults[index];
                              });
                            },
                          )
                        : PrefInformationCardMeal(
                            snapShotDocument: filteredResults[index],
                            cardColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            isSelected:
                                filteredResults[index] == _selectedSnapshot,
                            onSelected: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _selectedSnapshot = filteredResults[index];
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                  ),
                ),
              )),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 35,
              top: 25,
            ),
            child: SubmitSettingChangesButton(
              buttonText: 'Continue',
              cancelText: 'Cancel',
              cancelOnTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              continueOnTap: () {
                Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    context,
                    createRoute(FindingRecommendationScreen(
                      snapshotName: _selectedSnapshot,
                    )),
                    (route) => false);
              },
            ),
          ),
...
```

If you need any further information just give me a note. I would be very thankful if you could help me with this:)

---

Code Screen 4:

```
 class AskSomellierStep4Screen extends StatefulWidget {
      const AskSomellierStep4Screen({
        Key? key,
        required this.stepDescription,
        required this.wineOrMeal,
        required this.mealVSWine,
        required this.selectedCuisine,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      final String wineOrMeal;
      final String stepDescription;
      final bool mealVSWine;
      final String selectedCuisine;
    
      @override
      State<AskSomellierStep4Screen> createState() =>
          _AskSomellierStep4ScreenState();
    }
    
    class _AskSomellierStep4ScreenState extends State<AskSomellierStep4Screen> {
      QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>? _selectedSnapshot;
      List<String> dataLabel = [
        'Home',
        'Search',
        'Account',
      ];
      late Future resultsLoaded;
      List<IconData> data = [
        CustomIcons.home,
        CustomIcons.search,
        CustomIcons.user,
      ];
    
      getResults() async {
        var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection(widget.wineOrMeal)
            .where('type', isEqualTo: widget.selectedCuisine)
            .get();
        setState(() {
          allResults = data.docs;
        });
        filterResultsList();
        return data.docs;
      }
    
      List allResults = [];
    
      List filteredResults = [];
    
      onSearchChanged() {
        print(searchController.text);
        filterResultsList();
      }
    
      filterResultsList() {
        var showResults = [];
    
        if (searchController.text != '') {
          // we have a search parameter
          for (var searchSnapshot in allResults) {
            var name = searchSnapshot['name'].toLowerCase();
    
            if (name.contains(searchController.text.toLowerCase())) {
              showResults.add(searchSnapshot);
            }
          }
        } else {
          // we do not have a search parameter
          showResults = List.from(allResults);
        }
        setState(() {
          filteredResults = showResults;
        });
      }
    
      TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        searchController.addListener(onSearchChanged);
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        searchController.removeListener(onSearchChanged);
        searchController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      void didChangeDependencies() {
        super.didChangeDependencies();
        resultsLoaded = getResults();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
          body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              HomeScreenHeader(
                subText: 'Wine and Food',
                mainText: 'Ask your Somellier',
                boxWidth: 238,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 172,
                  top: 92,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'Step 4',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).indicatorColor,
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 97,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  widget.stepDescription,
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 35,
                  top: 25,
                ),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 35,
                      width: 320,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      left: 10,
                      top: 14.5,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 21,
                        width: 300,
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: searchController,
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Search',
                            hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              textStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      left: 320 - 35,
                      top: 119 - 110,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 17,
                        width: 17,
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                          'assets/icons/general/search.svg',
                          color: Theme.of(context).indicatorColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 35,
                  top: 15,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'Popular Choices',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 35,
                    top: 5,
                  ),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 370,
                    width: 320,
                    child: Center(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        itemCount: filteredResults.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) => widget.mealVSWine
                            ? PrefInformationCardWine(
                                snapShotDocument: filteredResults[index],
                                cardColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                isSelected:
                                    filteredResults[index] == _selectedSnapshot,
                                onSelected: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _selectedSnapshot = filteredResults[index];
                                  });
                                },
                              )
                            : PrefInformationCardMeal(
                                snapShotDocument: filteredResults[index],
                                cardColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                isSelected:
                                    filteredResults[index] == _selectedSnapshot,
                                onSelected: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _selectedSnapshot = filteredResults[index];
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )),
              Padding(
                padding: const Ed

geInsets.only(
              left: 35,
              top: 25,
            ),
            child: SubmitSettingChangesButton(
              buttonText: 'Continue',
              cancelText: 'Cancel',
              cancelOnTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              continueOnTap: () {
                _selectedSnapshot != null
                    ? () {
                        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                            context,
                            createRoute(FindingRecommendationScreen(
                              snapshotName: _selectedSnapshot,
                            )),
                            (route) => false);
                      }
                    : null;
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 15,
              left: 171,
            ),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 16,
                width: 47,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Go Back',
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).indicatorColor,
                        fontSize: 11,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Code Screen 5:

```
class FindingRecommendationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FindingRecommendationScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.snapshotName,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>? snapshotName;
  @override
  State<FindingRecommendationScreen> createState() =>
      _FindingRecommendationScreenState();
}

class _FindingRecommendationScreenState
    extends State<FindingRecommendationScreen> {
  bool progressDone = true;
  late Future<IconData> iconSnapshot;
  Future<bool> animationDone() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 3000), () {
      setState(() {
        progressDone = true;
      });
    });
    return progressDone;
  }

  Future<IconData> iconData(Future<bool> progress) async {
    if (await progress == true) {
      return Icons.home;
    }
    print('function used');
    return Icons.done;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 35,
              vertical: 100,
            ),
            child: Text(
              'Your Somellier is searching...',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Theme.of(context).indicatorColor,
                  fontSize: 24,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 200) / 2,
              right: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 200) / 2,
              top: 50,
            ),
            child: CircularPercentIndicator(
              radius: 120,
              lineWidth: 4.0,
              circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
              animation: true,
              animationDuration: 3000,
              percent: 1,
              // center: FutureBuilder<IconData>(
              //   future: iconData(animationDone()),
              //   builder: (context, snapshot) {
              //     return Icon(
              //       snapshot.data,
              //       color: Colors.white,
              //     );
              //   },
              // ),
              // center: const Icon(
              //   Icons.done_rounded,
              //   color: Colors.white,
              //   size: 90,
              // ),
              center: Text(
                'Finding Wine ',
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              progressColor: Theme.of(context).indicatorColor,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 35,
              right: 35,
              top: 200,
            ),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    context,
                    createRoute(const SomellierResultScreen()),
                    (route) => false);
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 50,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 70,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                    25,
                  ),
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    widget.snapshotName?['name'],
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).indicatorColor,
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Errormessage]

Comment: Can you add a narrowed down version of the code for the specific problem areas? Which field is not being initialized?

Comment: the field that im talking about is the _selectedSnapshot

Comment: I just left the rest in to understand how I got that

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

The problem with _selectedSnapshot is that you use it before you ever initialize it with a value.

In your code, you are using

```
isSelected: filteredResults[index] == _selectedSnapshot,
```

This causes the error because _selectedSnapshot has no value assigned yet. In your code you assign your value only, when the user taps one of the cards.

```
onSelected: () {
  setState(() {
    _selectedSnapshot = filteredResults[index];
  });
},
```

But you never get there, since the screen can't be build because of the error thrown.

## Solution

Instead of

```
late QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> _selectedSnapshot;
```

use

```
QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>? _selectedSnapshot = null;
```

With the ?-Operator you allow your variable _selectedSnapshot to be null.
This means in your context, the user has not yet chosen one option.

You may want to disable the continue button until the user has chosen an option:

```
continueOnTap: _selectedSnapshot != null ? () {    
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context,  createRoute(FindingRecommendationScreen( snapshotName: _selectedSnapshot, )), (route) => false); 
} : null,
```

This checks if _selectedSnapshot is not null. If so the user can continue. Otherwise the Button-Callback is null, which means nothing will happen, if the user presses continue.

Comment: I understand your solution but flutter still throws an error (the error message isn't displayed just a stack trace)

Comment: are there common problems that can occur here?

Comment: so because the data is a required parameter in the next screen I had to add a null check in the next screen with the bang operator ! can this make a difference?

Comment: The !-Operator checks if the variable is null and throws an error if so. So it wouldn't help you. Instead I would suggest you to force the use to make a choice by disabling the continue button until he has done so. Try this:

Comment: I just updated the answer to show you a way to disable a button

Comment: I uploaded the code and the error message but it keeps happening... I implemented the disabling of the button but it still doesn't seem to work... do you have any idea where this might be coming from?

Comment: What do you see on the device/simulator screen, when the error happens?
There seems to be a problem related to rendering, since a RenderErrorBox is created.
Can you see an error message on the device-screen?

Comment: Are there any warnings shown in the IDE for your code snippets?